# Search directory for a pair of files (same name, different extension)

Tags: c#, windows, directorysearcher

Given a directory with a listing of files with two different extensions but the same name (for for example, `a.xml` has a `a.out` along with it), how do I find XML files that do *not* have a .out file to go with it? I'm limited to Windows environments and only have Visual Studio at my disposal.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the following c# code. In the end, the code could be a bit shorter but it's fast enough for my needs and worked perfectly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace OrderFinder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string SearchDir = @"Y:\imported";
            string SearchExp = "*.xml";
            string MustHave = "{xmlfile}.out";
            string name, find;
            try
            {
                foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(SearchDir, SearchExp, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
                {
                    name = file.Substring(SearchDir.Length + 1);
                    find = SearchDir + "\\" + MustHave.Replace("{xmlfile}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));

                    if (!File.Exists(find))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[WARN] Mismatched: " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[ERR] Exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```